# Why the {{customer.wishlist}} not accessible to product-view.html big commerce-stencil?

Tags: bigcommerce, stencils

I am trying to get customer's wishlist list in product-view.html template in stencil but its not working, i am getting {{customer.name}} but not {{customer.wishlist}}

{{# if customer.wishlists.length '>' 1 }}
            {{lang 'account.wishlists.add_item'}}
            
                
                    **{{#each customer.wishlists}}** 
                     {{name}}
                    {{/each}}
                    
                
            

            {{else}}
            
            {{/if}}

Please if anyone have solution then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

**I got solution**
Add following in **pages>>product.html** then n then will able to get wishlist's data.

---

customer:
     wishlists:
        limit:10

---

When you create a store page that requires access to specific attributes (such as featured products, or customer information), you must first declare the attributes by including a front-matter block at the top of the page's template file

The attribute will then be accessible in that page's context: You will be able to access the attribute’s value by including Handlebars double braces around the attribute’s name in your HTML code.